# 'clicking' in cells containing hyperlinks to generate mailto

Tags: excel, vba

I am throwing together a quick VBA application in Excel for an office secret santa activity.  I have code that will take a list of names in column A, copy them and randomize them in column B and repeat until there are no matches where the participant is paired with themselves.  In addition, I have the cells in column F containing a hyperlink as follows:
(example from cell F10)

```
=HYPERLINK("mailto:" & A10 & "?subject=Shhhhh… Secret Santa" & "&body=The name of your receipient is:  " &B10, "Email")
```

So now I want a subroutine to simply roll down column F and 'click' on each hyperlink.
I have tried a few things that I found online but none of them matched exactly what I needed. I suspect my syntax blew so I'm not even going to provide the amusement to you. I've been away from coding for awhile :)
This 'should' just be a simple loop but I need the magic line in the middle:

```
Sub Generate_Emails()
Dim lastsanta
lastsanta = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
cur = 0
Do Until cur = lastsanta
------  Magic line that clicks Cells(cur, 6)
cur = cur + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

The end result, when run, should popup a buttload of email windows already filled in with destination a nd content so all I need to do is click send in each window (still looking at how to make that happen automatically but I think outlook won't allow it so people don't robo-spam)

Help please.

Comment: First point - there is no row 0.

Comment: Second point: this will get you blacklisted by you ISP without any effort at all :)

Comment: What you should do (in your one-off case) I think is look into how Outlook automation works. Collect the email addresses and put them into the Bcc: field. That would work for a reasonable number. If there are like thousands of e-mail addresses, look into a dedicated mailing service like MailChimp.

Comment: Have a look at this https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail5.htm for a slew of basic VBA stuff to perform

Comment: BigBen, yes, I understand there is no 0. that was just a thrown together example indicating that I want to use the index to loop through each cell to click. Sorry for my sloppiness

Comment: Amo van Boven, this is a list of approx 40 officemates with emails across my intranet.  No blacklisting as I am intentionally staying away from automatically sending email via script even if it was a larger list. But thank you for your concern.

Comment: Fourth.... thanks for the link.  I've poked around we searches and tried a variety of what seemed to be similar things with no success.  Given time, I'm sure I could eventually figure it out but in this case, I'm trying to get this 'event' rolling early next week so having a working script in place in short order is preferred.  Hence, I popped the question out here because I know there are lots of fellow geeks who love to help those of us who lack expertise in in particular tech areas :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For a = 1 To 10

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .to = Cells(a, 1).Value
        .Subject = "Secret Santa 2"
        .Body = "Secret Santa info from another cell"
        .Send
    End With
Next

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```

Comment: @BigBen, indeed.  Thanks.

Comment: But `Set OutApp` should be outside the loop.

Comment: I'll give this a try and see if it yields a usable result. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: This chunk of code will work for my purposes.  Thanks.